# Visual Studio C++ RegOpenKeyEx() registry Access is denied error Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, registry, windows-7-x64, permission-denied

I'm running a C++ program (which works great on 32 bit Win XP) on Windows 7 64 bit in debugger under Visual Studio 2010 and I am unable to open an existing registry key with the following code:

```
#define ACCESS  (KEY_WRITE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS)

HKEY hKey;
long dwErrorCode = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\MYTHING", 0, ACCESS|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);

if (dwErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{
// display error message
}
```

The error code returned is: 5 with the system message being "Access is Denied".

This does work if I run the Visual Studio 2010 as Admin, however I'd rather not have to do that.  Can anybody offer a suggestion?

Update:  I forgot to mention, what I am doing here is porting legacy code from Windows XP.  As such, I don't have the option of changing the fundamental structure of how this software was written.  Since the legacy code uses the registry, that is what the ported code must do also.

Also, I would rather not make changes to my specific computer -- since that means I would have to change every computer that I want to run this on.  This could get messy as there are a lot of machines affected.  For example, I don't want to turn off UAC for the entire machine.

Further update:  I haven't found a solution that I'm happy with.  Have decided to ignore error code 5 for purposes of debugging and that seems to be working well enough for now.  I'm trying to understand how standard apps like Word, Firefox, etc appear to be using the registry for all kinds of settings and yet are not elevated nor do I have to give them special permissions to make changes to the registry?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better solution to your problem, rather than fighting UAC?

Comment: You aren't meant to write there unless you are an installer or similar. Time to learn about standard user.

Comment: I'm storing and retrieving settings pertaining to the device which this software is embedded into -- settings which need to be persistent.  Not sure if that qualifies me as an "installer"?

Comment: Please note my updates to the question in response to comments.

Comment: Well, if you can't change the app, or run it elevated, the system has to give (permissions or UAC off). Welcome to UAC!

Comment: Obviously I'm a bit confused, thanks for helping me sort this out.  Do all programs which use the registry have to be elevated, or given special permissions?  I had the impression that most of the Win 7 apps that I use day in and day out utilize the registry to store information, and I haven't done anything to elevate those apps nor have I given them special permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the process in elevated mode, or turn off UAC. You can of course assign access rights to your specific registry key that allows you access.

Comment: Special access not to be recommended.

Comment: I would prefer not to have to go in and change the access rights of the specific registry key on every machine that I use.  If by elevated mode you mean running as admin, that does work (see my original question) but I would prefer a better solution.   For the same reason, I don't want to turn off the UAC.

Comment: It sounds like you want to access something that requires special permission, but you don't want to give the permission (neither through elevation nor ACL change).  From a security standpoint, system wide settings, like device configuration, require more security since they can affect any user on the system.  Allowing an unelevated user to change a device's config could cause some serious problems.

Comment: @user995048 I see what you are saying.  But don't most apps (Word, outlook, browsers) that run in Windows 7 make use of the registry without having to be elevated in any way?

Comment: AFter a lot of messing around with this, I have decided to give this one the correct answer nod.  By assigning the User Full Control access rights to my registry key, whether it be 64 or 32 bit registry, my program is happy now.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found the answer to my question so I'll post it here in case anybody else needs it for future reference.  This thread turned out to be helpful even though it is actually on the topic of C#:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/netfx64bit/thread/92f962d6-7f5e-4e62-ac0a-b8b0c9f552a3

Basically, I needed to change my permission to read the 32 bit registry instead of the 64 bit one like so:

```
HKEY hKey;
long dwErrorCode = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\MYTHING", 0, ACCESS|KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey);

if (dwErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{
// display error message
}
```

Voila, everything works now!  Thanks for your efforts everyone.

Update:  it turns out this didn't work as well on my other machine, which led me to discover that someone must have changed access rights to the 32 bit registry on one of my machines.  So it is still necessary to give the User access rights to the registry key you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. I have solved using following:

```
LPCTSTR subKey = TEXT("Software\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths");
LONG openRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey, 0, KEY_WOW64_32KEY && KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
```